# Remove duplicates from unsorted Linked List

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, linked-list

[Quesn link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-duplicates-from-an-unsorted-linked-list/)

I have written the code but it's not giving correct output but logically  it is correct , I don't know why it is giving wrong output , even i dubug it many times but i think that problem is hitting my blind spot .. so Plz help me and me this code run plz plz

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Node {
  int data;
  struct Node *next;
  Node(int x) {
    data = x;
    next = NULL;
  }
};
void print(Node *root){
    while(root!=NULL){
        cout<<root->data<<" ";
        root=root->next;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
class Solution
{   private:
    void solve(Node* &current,Node* &nxt){
        if(nxt==NULL){
            return;
        }
        Node *temp=nxt;
        Node *previous=current;;
        while(nxt!=NULL){
            if(current->data==nxt->data){
                if(nxt->next=NULL){
                    delete nxt;
                    previous->next=NULL;
                    return;
                }
                 previous->next=nxt->next;
                 delete nxt;
                 nxt=previous->next;
    
            }else{
                nxt=nxt->next;
                previous=previous->next;
            }
        }
        nxt=temp;
        
        solve(current->next,nxt->next);
    }
    public:
    //Function to remove duplicates from unsorted linked list.
    Node * removeDuplicates( Node *head) 
    {  if(head==NULL){
          return NULL;
       }`enter code here`
       if(head->next==NULL){
           return head;
       }
       Node *temp=head;
       Node *next=temp->next;
       solve(head,next);
       return temp;
    }
};

int main(){
        int k;
        cin>>k;
        struct Node *head=NULL;
        struct Node *temp=head;
        for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
            int data;
            cin>>data;
            if(head==NULL){
                head=temp=new Node(data);
            }else{
                temp->next=new Node(data);
                temp=temp->next;
            }
        }
    Solution ob;
    Node *result=ob.removeDuplicates(head);
    print(result);
    return 0;
}
```

[See hightlighted part i think problem starts from that part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeKqV.png)

Comment: If the logic were in fact correct, you wouldn’t be here.

Answer (score 1):

Quick scan shows this error

```
 if (nxt->next = NULL)
```

I bet you mean

```
 if (nxt->next == NULL)
```

My compiler was kind enough to warn me

> 1>C:\work\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.cpp(40): warning C4706: assignment within conditional expression

Comment: Thanks dude, it's working good now...